# AnalyserNode.fftSize of 32768 not working on IOS 11

Tags: javascript, iphone, webrtc, fft, ios11

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize indicates that AnalyserNode.fftSize values are non-zero power of 2 integers from 32 to 32768. And this seems to work everywhere EXCEPT IOS/Safari 11 in which case it caps out at 2048. Even Safari 11 on my Macbook support the larger 32768 value.

Can anyone confirm this is true and/or a workaround to get higher resolution FFT bins. My alternative is to use ooura fft javascript but I suspect webRTC is a better long term solution if not more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

3 year late, but...

This seems to be correct. I've tried using different fftSize values on several devices running IOS/Safari 11. The highest supported value across all devices is 2048.